# Android Media Scan takes too long

Tags: java, android, media, android-mediascanner

I'm using the code below to `scan all media/mp3` files on the device, but it takes too long when there is a lot of music on the device.

I was wondering if there is a faster way to get and show all musics or not?

Note: the code doesn't cause crash or hang up or any other thing...

```
class GetLocals extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    SongCover_lc.clear();
    SongID_lc.clear();
    Singer_lc.clear();
    Path_lc.clear();
    AlbumName_lc.clear();
    SongName_lc.clear(); 
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    try {
      String[] STAR = {"*"};
      Cursor cursor;
      Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
      String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";

      cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, STAR, selection, null, null);

      if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
          do {
            String songName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
            String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
            String albumName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
            String singer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
            String songid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));

            MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            mmr.setDataSource(path);
            byte[] artBytes = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
            if (artBytes != null) {
              InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(mmr.getEmbeddedPicture());
              Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
              SongCover_lc.add(bm);
            } else {
              SongCover_lc.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.color.white));
            }

            SongName_lc.add(songName);
            AlbumName_lc.add(albumName);
            Path_lc.add(path);
            Singer_lc.add(singer);
            SongID_lc.add(songid);

          } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println("CAAAAAAAAAAATCH");
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    lazyAdapter_localSongs = new LazyAdapter_LocalSongs(activity,SongName_lc,Singer_lc,SongCover_lc,AlbumName_lc,Path_lc);
    listviewloclas.setAdapter(lazyAdapter_localSongs);
  }
}
```

Comment: Mind that scan speed might depend heavily on the SD card in use (if on external SD) respective on the device (and which internal memory H/W is used).

Comment: @Fildor well i have tested on many devices and even emulator with free space! but i still has a low speed

Comment: Also, you could split this in: 1. Fetch List of Music , 2. Later update View with Album covers. You will probably not show the complete list always, so no need to fetch all bitmaps. Just fetch the pics you actually need (and maybe prefetch the next few ones that the user could page to)

Comment: @Fildor ill check it out! thanks

Comment: Secondly, it may be beneficial for memory consumption to "forget" covers that ran out of view.

Comment: well i never had a problem with that and now im trying to store data on database for better speed in second launches! ill share it here! @Fildor

Comment: Did you find a solution? on Android 10 (Q) `Download Manager` scans too late for `allowScanningByMediaScanner` deprecated. The problem will be solved only by restarting the phone. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> I was wondering if there is a faster way to get 
> and show all musics ...
```

Replace your array-based adapter with a [CursorAdapter](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter) that will load the songs on demand.

So instead of pre-loading 1000 songs into arrays before your listview/grid becomes usable you just load the 10 songs that are visible at a time.